# How to set absolute text size on android (TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM)

Tags: android

I am writing an app about eye test. It is necessary to set the standard text size. I used the following code but it showed what I did not expect.

```
            Typeface type=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Optotypes.ttf");
            textView2.setTypeface(type);
            textView2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM,25);       
            textView2.setText(randomLetter);
```

I expected the textview show a 2.5cm letter but it is not the exact length/height still. 
This situation appear also on different device.

The next problem is that the size is different between the original font and ttf I added. (the original font didn't show the text with 2.5cm also.

Is my code wrong or anything else i missed ? Thanks guys . it is important to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing how Android handles text sizes.

In Android, you should specify text size in SP units, so Android can scale it accordingly to the user's font size preferences. Never specify hardcoded pixels or centimeters.

Check this references for documentation on the subject:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textSize

[What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

If you want to set the text size in SP programatically, you can do this

```
// same as android:textSize="15sp" in XML
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
```

-- EDIT

Keep in mind that by just setting a certain text size it doesn't mean that every letter will be of that size. Remember that there are multiple letters with multiple sizes. For instance, with a size of 20mm, this is what you get

[image]
[image]

Because Android needs to accommodate every possible character in a textview with the size you provided. That being said, textSize is not 100% accurate to what you provide to it.

If this is not enough for you, please provide more details of the problem you have at hands.

Comment: So when I set text size in sp , is it possible to result the 25mm height in different screens?

Comment: It should say I still dont know how can I get a text height with 25mm as my app need in different screens

Comment: Actully, My app is a eye test app.it shows some letters which have the same height. The users stay away from 3m to read a letter which is 25mm tall. So I dont know how to set text size/height.

Comment: The following is the link which is my text font [http://www.optiboard.com/forums/showthread.php/33269-Snellen-Optotype](http://www.optiboard.com/forums/showthread.php/33269-Snellen-Optotype). thank you so much!

Comment: I wonder what exactly does number do in textSize. For example on your picture green zone's height is more than 20 mm, its width is less than it, diagonal isn't 20mm too. So where is 20mm ?